# How to display individual blog post by its ID in Angular/Express/MongoDB app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I can't figure out how to get a single blog post by its ID -- I'm very new to this.

So far my main blog app has an ng-repeat which can get all posts. What I want is to be able to click on the name of the post and be show only that post and nothing else -- eventually I want to be able to delete and edit by ID as well.

I know filters exist, but I am not sure how to have a filter enabled by clicking, or how to make sure that when I click it, it will filter by that _id.

My 'post.html' looks as follows -

```
<div ng-controller="PostController" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <strong>
                <a href ng-click="selectTab('viewPost')">{{post.title}}</a>
            </strong> created on {{post.time | date: 'MM/dd/yy @ h:mma'}}
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{post.body}} <br>
        {{post._id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I have the ng-click directive set up to show this-

```
        <div ng-show="isSelected('viewPost')">
          <view-post></view-post>
        </div>
```

Which is a custom directive linking this file --

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        <strong>
            <a href>{{postById.title}}</a>
        </strong> created on {{postById.time | date: 'MM/dd/yy @ h:mma'}}
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {{postById.body}}


</div>
</div>
```

When that template is shown, the expressions are missing altogether.

I have a getPost function in my controller 'PostController' but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
    $scope.getPost = function () {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/blog/:post_id', data: $scope.postById})
        .then(function(response){
             //your code in case the post succeeds
            console.log(response);
            })
        .catch(function(err){
            //your code in case your post fails
            console.log(err);
            });

        }
```

My API works using Postman, as I can get/update/delete posts on that route. At the moment I have nothing going on in the address bar, no routes in particular -- everything is based around custom directives displaying the templates I want when clicked.

I had thought it could be a problem with the scope of my controllers.

A snippet of my HTML might make it more apparent--

```
<body ng-controller="PanelController">

<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="cover-container">
      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <nav-bar></nav-bar>
      </div>

      <div ng-controller="PostController">
        <div ng-show="isSelected('blog')">
          <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: 'time':true">
            <blog-post></blog-post>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="isSelected('about')">
          <about-page></about-page>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="isSelected('contact')">
          <contact></contact>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="isSelected('createPost')">
          <create-post></create-post>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="isSelected('viewPost')">
          <view-post></view-post>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Hopefully this makes some sense to someone. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Just to make it a bit more complete, here's the API for getting posts by ID -

```
router.route('/blog/:post_id')

.get(function(req, res) {
    Post.findById(req.params.post_id, function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(post);
        }
    });
})

.put(function(req, res) {

    Post.findById(req.params.post_id, function(err, post) {

        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            post.title = req.body.title;
            post.body = req.body.body;
        }

        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'Post updated!' });
            }
        });

    });
})

.delete(function(req, res) {
    Post.remove({
        _id: req.params.post_id
    }, function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to display different content based on changing state - that's what angular apps typically use routing for - check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.  Basically, instead of a bunch of ng-shows for each state/page, you register those states/pages with the $stateProvider, then transition between states/pages when the user clicks things.

Comment: `$http` is different than `$resource` ... you can't use placeholders for routeParams in url string

Comment: I'll take a good look at ui-router and $resource when I'm not on night shift! Thanks very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your response data to `$scope.post` It would look something like this...

```
$http(...).then(function(response) {
    $scope.post = response.post;
});
```

Comment: Originally I was using ng-click to execute getPost as well as the isSelected() function with the post ID as a parameter, which I used concatenated with the url in the get request, instead of the :post_id as it is now.

Thanks for the reply!

When I change it, it says it's not a function in the JS console.